# Upgraded from JDK 1.8 to JDK 11 but getting ProviderImpl class not found exception

Tags: java-8, java-11

I have upgraded my eclipse app from JDK 1.8 to JDK 11 but getting below exception while running the app. please help.

```
  javax.xml.ws.WebServiceException: Provider com.sun.xml.internal.ws.spi.ProviderImpl not found
!SESSION            at javax.xml.ws.spi.FactoryFinder.newInstance(FactoryFinder.java:68)
              at javax.xml.ws.spi.FactoryFinder.find(FactoryFinder.java:166)
              at javax.xml.ws.spi.Provider.provider(Provider.java:142)
              at javax.xml.ws.Service.<init>(Service.java:92)
              
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.xml.internal.ws.spi.ProviderImpl
              at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:581)
              at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178)
              at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521)
              at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.ContextFinder.loadClass(ContextFinder.java:139)
              at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521)
              at javax.xml.ws.spi.FactoryFinder.safeLoadClass(FactoryFinder.java:187)
              at javax.xml.ws.spi.FactoryFinder.newInstance(FactoryFinder.java:65)
              ... 31 more
```

Comment: What do you mean by _my eclipse app_? Do you mean the actual IDE or do you mean a Java project that you created in Eclipse? What version of Eclipse are you using? How did you upgrade from JDK 1.8 to JDK 11? Did you change the preferences of your workspace in Eclipse?

Comment: Its an Eclipse RCP app what i have created using eclipse IDE. I am using Eclipse 4.13. I have configured JRE as jdk 11 and selected JDK 11 in project build path. @Abra